# Segmentation fault função fgets

Tags: c, string, arquivo

Estou tendo um problema de `segmentation fault` na abertura de arquivos `txt`. Eu sei que para manipuação de `strings`, liguagens de mais alto nível, porém não tenho como aprender agora, por isso estou utilizando `C`. Meu problema consiste em ler uma lista com nome de quatro mil arquivos, cujo formato de cada um é o seguinte:

```
0.00053714,0.00053714,-0.00061595,0.30794,-0.00061595,0.30794,1.0001,1,0.0050735
```

Meu programa pega o elemento que corresponda a posição definida pela variável `posição_elemento=6`, nesse caso específico igual a seis.
O problema que esta ocorrendo é que não consigo realizar essa operação de pegar o sexto elemento nos meus quatro mil arquivos, ocorrendo `segmentation fault`. Creio que seja algum parâmetro errado que estou passando para `while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), arquivo2))`. Segue abaixo o meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void subs(char* buffer){
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++){
      if(buffer[i] == '\n')
         buffer[i] = 0; // Contrabarra zero: fim do buffer
   }
}
int main(){

   FILE *lista, *lista_nova;
   FILE *arquivo, *arquivo2;

   char buffer[50];
   char leia, line[256], *valor, *valor_escolhido;
   int cont_elemento = 1, posicao_elemento=6, i=0;
   float tempo;

   lista_nova = fopen ("lista_nova.txt", "r");

   arquivo = fopen("velocidades.txt", "wt");
   if (arquivo == NULL){
      printf ("Error opening velocidades\n");
      return 0;
      }

   while( !feof(lista_nova) ){
      fgets(buffer, 50, lista_nova);
      subs(buffer);
      arquivo2 = fopen(buffer, "r");

      if (arquivo2 == NULL){
         printf ("Error opening buffer.txt\n");
         return 0;
      }

      printf ("Arquivo = %s\n", buffer);

      while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), arquivo2))
    {
        //Pega o primeiro elemento separado por uma virgula.
        valor = strtok(line,",");

        //Obtem os outros elementos até o fim da linha.
        while (valor != NULL)
        {
            //printf("%s\n",valor);
            valor = strtok(NULL, ",");

            cont_elemento++;

            if (cont_elemento == posicao_elemento)
                valor_escolhido = valor;
        }
    }
    tempo=0.1*i;
    fprintf(arquivo,"%f\t%s\n",tempo,valor_escolhido);
    i++;
    cont_elemento=1;
   }

   fclose(arquivo);
   fclose(arquivo2);
   fclose (lista_nova);

return(0);
}
```

Comment: Para meteres a string `"0.00053714,0.00053714,-0.00061595,0.30794,-0.00061595,0.30794,1.0001,1,0.0050735"` num array precisas de, pelo menos, 82 bytes. Com 50 bytes o `fgets()` lê a string em duas vezes: a primeira com 49 caracteres, a segunda com os restantes incluindo o `'\n'`.

Comment: @pmg mas esses 50 são para ler o nome do arquivo que será aberto e não a string.  O responsável pela leitura da mesma tem 256.

Comment: Ah! Erro meu. Uma coisa que deves corrigir é o primeiro ciclo `while`. Deves controlar o ciclo com o resultado da função `fgets()` (como fizeste para o ciclo interior) em vez do resultado da função `feof()`.

Comment: Desculpe @pmg mas não entendi o que você quis dizer. Tem como repetir por favor?

Comment: `while (!feof(...)) { /* ... */ }` esta errado: a maneira correcta é `while (fgets(...)) { /* ... */ }`. A funcao `feof()` determina se o ultimo erro ocorrido se deve a se ter atingido o fim do ficheiro; chamar essa funcao sem indicacao de erro anterior causa leituras extra do ficheiro.

Comment: Obrigado @pmg , já corrigi mas continuo com o mesmo problema de Segmentation fault, quando ele vai abrir determinado numero de arquivos. Atualmente ele para de executar o programa, não conseguindo mais abrir depois do arquivo número 1016. Quando executo em outro computador, o máximo que consigo abrir varia. Já consegui 560 e deu erro, como também 1200 em outro e então da erro da mesma forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O "open" do `arquivo2` e o seu "close" não estão ao mesmo nível.

Um é executado dentro dum ciclo, outro é executado fora do ciclo.

```
while (/* ... */) {
    /* ... */
    arquivo2 = fopen(/* ... */);
    /* ... */
}
/* ... */
fclose(arquivo2);
```

Sugestão: usa um estilo de indentação coerente.

Comment: Realmente não tinha me atentado a isso. Um erro ridículo que eu não percebi. Muito Obrigado @pmg por corrigir esses dois erros.